# Middleware EJS does not render any JPG file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i'm trying to develop a very simple NodeJS server with EJS.
This little server have to render a little HTML page with just a line of text and a jpg file inside.

Everyhing goes ok but the jpg file: this is not loaded by the server.

In the code i have specified express.static path but nothing to do.

I tried locally (on my 2 computers) and here, in my home, it's all ok. On the remote server the jpg has not been loaded.
I tried 2 different server of 2 different providers but the result it's the same.

This is my image.js file

```
const http = require("http")
var url = require("url")

const express = require("express");
const appExpress = express();
const router = express.Router();
const application_root = __dirname;
const application_port = 5000


appExpress.engine("html", require('ejs').renderFile);
appExpress.use("/", router);

appExpress.use(express.static(application_root + "/public"));


appExpress.get("*", function (req, res, next) {
  res.render((application_root + "/public/indice.html"), {})
  next();
});


// *********** CARICAMENTO PAGINA PRINCIPALE *************
function caricaPagina(res, tipologia_domande) {
    res.render((application_root + "/public/indice.html"), {})
}



appExpress.listen(application_port, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${application_port}`);
})
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Prova caricamento immagine</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div><img src="public/images/Sfondi/Slider.jpg"></div>
  Testo di prova per caricamento pagina
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see the project is very very simple and small but i'm going crazy about it :-(

Thanks to anyone will help me :-)

*** UPDATE ***

I tried to run this code

```
appExpress.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile(application_root + '/public/images/Sfondi/Slider.jpg'));
```

This code it's ok and the image has been correctly loaded.
So it's not a path problem but rather an html loading problem.
Is there a res.render() problem with html and image file?

*** UPDATE 2 ***

Ok, this is the situation:
if i use this code (with the sendFile function) the middleware **load the html page** loading the image but **does not execute** the javascript code inside the html page.

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/indice.html"), {path_image:path_image})
```

If i choose to use this code (res.render) the middleware **execute the javascript** inside the html page but **does not load** the image.

```
res.render((application_root + "/public/indice.html"), {path_image:path_image})
```

Anyone has some solution for this incredible problem? I read all the web but it seems i'm the only one to have this problem.

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Typo: You have `public` in the file path **twice**. Once from the URL and again from the configuration of `static`

Comment: Aside: `const router = express.Router();` and `appExpress.use("/", router);` are pointless. You don't attach any routes to it.

Comment: @JonasWilms — 1. `<img src="public/` 2. `static(application_root + "/public"));`

Comment: @JonasWilms — The entire point of the static module is to relate the folder structure to URLs.

Comment: @quentin aaah, now I get your point, we do mean the same thing.

Comment: @JonasWilms — I think you misunderstood my meaning. The file path the code is **trying** to access has two `public`s in it. The **real** file path probably doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You serve the public folder directly on the main route, thus your image won't be reachable via `http://yourserver/public/images/...` but rather via `http://yourserver/images/`.

I wouldn't keep that though as for every request Express has to check the local folder if a file exists. It makes sense to move the file serving to /public:

```
appExpress.use("/public", express.static(application_root + "/public/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

when you add this code `appExpress.use(express.static(application_root + "/public"));`

that mining the static look like any type of media as an image in this file 
when want to use any type don't  write in the path or src the public because it found when used a static file 
the path without used the public

```
  <div><img src="/images/Sfondi/Slider.jpg"></div>
[read this wat meaing for static][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**.

For those who could have the same problem: the provider told me to put all .js apps outside the html_public folder. But outside that folder, other files couldn't be served (such images or other), neither if i put onyl the .,js files outside the html_public and pointing images (for example) inside the html_public. 
So i put all inside html_public folder, changed the paths and all has been ok.

You can closed this thread, thank you.